# Html/CSS filter on img with Hover but text that aperes disturbs the hover function and lets the filter go away+text

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

sorry for my bad Title xD

What im trying to do: I have an Image and when I hover over it, it gest grayed out and a text aperes over the piucture.

My Problem is: When you hover over the text the filter+text go away because the text covered the picture.

Is there a way to fix that?

Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: you need to share your html & css code or create a fiddle

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: the solution is to have a parent element that wraps the two, and trigger the text to be shown on `:hover` of the parent element - not the image. but I don't want to guess at whatever your current code is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look something like this:

```
<div class="hover-wrapper" onmouseover="showText('hover-text-1')">
  <div class="hover-text" id="hover-text-1">My Text</div>
  <img class="hover-img" src="mypath/myimage.jpg">
</div>
```

Do your mouseover event on the wrapper div tag  instead of the img tag and use it to toggle the display CSS on the hover-text you should be all good.